# How to write a case list pattern matching in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I want to do something like the following Go code:

```
 switch c {
    case ' ', '\t', '\n', '\f', '\r':
        return true
 }
```

But I can't find an example in the OCaml manual.

Is this possible in OCaml?

Comment: You're looking for the 'match" keyword and "pattern matching".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OCaml doesn't have `switch` statements. It has "pattern matching" which is something a bit more general than a `switch` statement.

You can read more about this [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html)

Your Go code could be translated to this (from the top of my head):

```
match c with 
| ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\012' (* '\f' *) | '\r' -> true
| _ -> false
```

Comment: This answer is essentially perfect, but I think it's worth pointing out that Go treats "switch" as a statement only, while "match" in OCaml is an expression, which we can treat as we would any other expression. This is a huge part of being able to write programs from a functional programming perspective.

Answer (score 0):

ShadowMitia has provided [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68572882/15261315) but it's important to keep the actual goal in mind. If we want to determine if a character is a whitespace character, we could simply check for its membership in a list.

```
let is_space ch =
  List.mem ch [' '; '\t'; '\n'; '\r'; '\012']
```

Another approach would convert the character to a string, trim the string, removing leading and trailing whitespace, and then check for equality with `""`.

```
let is_space ch = 
  ch 
  |> String.make 1 
  |> String.trim 
  |> (=) ""
```